# Module is not getting mocked while using @patch annotation

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest

This is my project directory structure

```
project 
   |
   |---------src
   |          |---------__init__.py
   |          |---------main.py
   |          |---------tools
   |                      |------__init__.py
   |                      |------tool_a
   |                      
   |                      
   |--------tests
              |
              |---------__init__.py
              |---------test_fun.py
```

and this is a simple test I am trying to write but it doesn't seem to mock with the @patch annotation

```
#main.py
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(sys.path[0], '..'))
from src.tools.tool_a import fun


def main_fun():
    return fun()
```

```
#tool_a.py

def fun():
    return 10
```

```
#test_fun.py

import os
import sys

from unittest.mock import patch
from src.main import main_fun


@patch('src.tools.tool_a.fun')
def test_main_fun(mock_fun):
    mock_fun.return_value = 1
    assert 1 == main_fun()
    mock_fun.assert_called()
```

I think it's the way directory is structured because if I have both `tool_a.py` and `main.py` in the same directory then the test works but doesn't seem to work here with this setup.

Comment: You have to patch `src.main.fun` if you do the import this way (`from x.y import fun`).

Comment: This seems to work but don't understand why? I patched the import the same way used in main.py.

Comment: Check [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) in the documentation.